# can not do "npm install -g composer-cli" in terminal Mac OS

Tags: command-line-interface

my purpose: Install the CLI tools.
[enter link description here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html#appendix)
when I try to use this command :"npm install -g composer-cli". I got this feeback:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLQjn.jpg)

my nvm version is 0.33.0.
my npm version is 5.6.0.
my Node version isv8.9.4
my Mac is Version is 10.12.6.

Does any guru know how to install this composer or ,like the terminal said "install peer dependencies yourself"

Comment: Are you sure it's not installed? You can't type `composer` and <kbd>enter</kbd> in your terminal?

Comment: This is a way to install composer on npm, you could search it by google on npmjs.com.